# the display word gets cut off 1 position

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

In the following code, there is a column that gets displayed called 
'All day event'  for some reason here the 't' is getting cut off. can you point me if there is any value here too large that would cause this?

```xml
<dxe:CheckEdit x:Name="chkAllDay" Margin="0,6,202,4" Grid.Column="2"
     Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource SchedulerControlStringIdConverter},
               ConverterParameter=Form_AllDayEvent,
               Converter={StaticResource SchedulerControlStringIdConverter}}"
     EditValue="{Binding Controller.AllDay}" IsReadOnly="{Binding ReadOnly}"
     IsEnabled="True" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="81" />
```

Comment: This is not enough code.  My guess is the problem is coming from the converter, but this is also not a standard control

Comment: your CheckEdit has Width fixed to 81 pixels and also fixed Margins. From this snippet I cannot guess what is the whole layout, but be sure to re-calculate those values. Maybe you've just accidentally got 5px off and the remaining area is too small for the text?

Comment: thanks Quetz, i made the width = 87 and it appears.

Comment: @Quetzalcoatl, please put your comment into an answer so that this question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Your `CheckEdit` has its `Width` fixed to 81 pixels <strike>and also fixed Margins</strike>*. From your code snippet I cannot guess how the whole layout looks, but be sure to re-calculate those values. Maybe you've just accidentally got 5px off and the remaining area is too small for the text?

*) I said about Margin, but I've mistaken them with Padding. Margin is not relevant here, they it's the outer spacing' and does not count to the Width. OTOH, the Padding would. I think [here's one good explanation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751709.aspx)